# Latex index prints additional undesired empty page after custom cover in last page

Tags: texmaker, makeindex

I am using TexMaker to write my thesis, using this template https://github.com/jaredjstewart/Masters-Project. I have a first cover, three chapters, a bibliography, an index, then a last 4th cover page I add.

**My problem is** that the index prints another empty page after my last cover page, with INDEX header (see image below).

A MWE is

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,english,onehalfspacing,dvipsnames]{MastersDoctoralThesis}
...
\usepackage[capbesideposition=right,capbesidesep=quad]{floatrow}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[intoc=true]

\usepackage[natbib=true,backend=biber,style=alphabetic,sorting=nyt,
backref=true,isbn=false,eprint=false]{biblatex}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
backrefpage = {return page}, % cited on page
backrefpages = {return pages} % cites on pages
}
\addbibresource{bibliographie.bib}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\pagestyle{plain}
\include{couverture}
\mainmatter
\pagestyle{thesis}

\include{Chapters/Intro/Introduction}
\include{Chapters/Chapter1/Chapter1}
\include{Chapters/Chapter11/Chapter11}
\include{Chapters/Chapter3/Chapter3}
\include{Chapters/Conclu/Conclusion}
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
\cleardoublepage
\printindex
\cleardoublepage
\include{Chapters/4eme_couv/4eme_couv}
\end{document}
```

Yet, I have that additional INDEX page after the 4th cover. I tried to make index two page long by adding entries, but then the additional page is still there at the end. See the image, the problem is indicated by the arrow. I would like my document to stop at the black line, just after the last cover.

[image: Screenshot of the end of my document. The bibliography ends, the index is displayed, my 4th cover, then another index page with IDEX header.]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding

> \thispagestyle{empty}

after the command that includes the 4th cover. Thus the code is modified as follows

```
\include{Chapters/4eme_couv/4eme_couv}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\end{document}
```

This removes the header and page number on the last page that is annoying me. The last additionnal page is still here anyway. I do not know why latex adds this extra page after the last include. At least it is blank now.